# How to solve covered by other columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance

[image: How to let the clicked one over others]

This is a layout I created, and add a jquery function that will enlarge and then resize to origin after click on any one of columns. The big problem is that the effect is covered by other columns around the clicked one. How can I improve it?

Here is my code:
`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/loeghy/3a4drvg7/

PS: this website haven't jquery plugin

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- it's hard to solve a problem without seeing the code. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code.

But I suggest, in the function that happens on a click, you change the z-index of the clicked element to a high number, then change it back to 0:

```js
$("#element-id").css("z-index", "1000");
```

Comment: Here is my click order: 1303, 1304, then 1303. The second click of 1303 is overlaid by 1304. How can I solve it?

Comment: Fixed it for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/3a4drvg7/2/

(For your future fiddles: You can add jQuery with the gear symbol in the javascript window)

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question I would like to ask: how can do this?  1. enlarge --> 2. rotate 360 --> 3. diminish --> 4. change color?  Your sample have done 1,3,4. How to add rotation?

Comment: animating rotation is not possible with jquery yet...i recommend using anime.js for this, it handles css properties like `transform` and the `rotate` function much better:
http://animejs.com/